# Sales order grid in magento2?

Tags: magento2, grid, magento2.2

How to delete specific 
column in sales order grid in magento2?
I have set **enable_comment** yes/no configuration in `store->configuration`.

How to remove the admin grid comment column if i have select enable_comment **no**
option.

How to do this based on Module configuration setting.

Thanks